# ¿Como sumar un valor a cada elemento de un arreglo en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, bucles

Tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio y no he encontrado nadie que hable de como sumar a cada elemento un valor especifico, debo usar el ciclo `for`, espero me puedan ayudar:

Teniendo el siguiente arreglo:

```
miArreglo = [101,102,103,104,105,106]
```

Elabora el código en el que le sumes 5 a cada elemento del arreglo, y lo muestres indicando qué lugar ocupa el elemento en el arreglo.

Ejemplo: El elemento 0 del arreglo es (X) y su valor final es (X+5).

Comment: Sabes hacer un for, para recorrer los elementos?

Comment: con un for ... in o for ... of o   con un for bucle normal o con el iterador forEach opciones tienes muchas

Comment: "no he encontrado nadie", acá tampoco lo encontrarás. No sabemos hacer tareas.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Bienvenido. Podes usar [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Explicación:

Prácticamente, lo que necesitas es recorrer todos los elementos e ir sumando a cada uno de los elementos en cada recorrido. Entonces, vendría bien usar el ciclo [**`for`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) en este caso. Con el ciclo `for` puedes recorrer cada elemento por cada bucle que haga el `for`. Te muestro un ejemplo básico para que entiendas bien como funciona:

---

##### Vamos por partes:

Aquí el ciclo `for` va a ir repitiéndose y mostrando el mensaje `miArreglo.length` veces, en donde `miArreglo.length` es el tamaño de tu arreglo (la cantidad de elementos que tiene), y esto sería `6`.

```js
let miArreglo = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106];

for (let i = 0; i < miArreglo.length; i++) {
  console.log(`Elemento ${i}`);
}
```

---

Ahora, en cada recorrido que haga el `for`, también podemos ingresar a los elementos del arreglo con `miArreglo[i]`, en donde `i` va a ir incrementando desde `0` hasta `5`. Aquí indicamos que `i` comience desde `0` porque las posiciones de los arreglos parten desde `0`, es por eso que inicializamos a `i` con su valor `0`.

```js
let miArreglo = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106];

for (let i = 0; i < miArreglo.length; i++) {
  console.log(`El elemento ${i} del arreglo es ${miArreglo[i]}`);
}
```

---

Y pues hasta aquí ya lo tendrías, ya hemos accedido a los elementos del arreglo, pues solo faltaría sumarle `5` a cada una de ellas, usando `miArreglo[i] + 5`:

```js
let miArreglo = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106];

for (let i = 0; i < miArreglo.length; i++) {
  console.log(`El elemento ${i} del arreglo es ${miArreglo[i]} y su valor final es ${miArreglo[i] + 5}`);
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo revisar [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) en javascript
La respuesta en javascript básico es la siguiente

```javascript
let miArreglo = [101,102,103,104,105,106]
function sumaValorAArreglo(arreglo, valor){
//el length indica que tome el tamaño del arreglo para que recorra todos los items
  for(let x = 0; x < miArreglo.length; x++){
    let mensaje = "el valor en " + x + " es " + miArreglo[x];
    miArreglo[x] += valor; 
    mensaje += " y sumado " + valor + " es " + miArreglo[x];
    console.log(mensaje);
    //esto es lo mismo que esto: miArreglo[x] = miArreglo[x] + valor;
    //es decir a cada item le sumas valor
  }
}
sumaValorAArreglo(miArreglo, 6)
```

sin embargo trata de usar ya las nuevas formas para realizarlo, por ejemplo en este caso te seria útil [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Es una mejor opción dado que hay me nos margen de error.

```javascript
let miArreglo = [101,102,103,104,105,106]
let arregloSumado = (valor) => miArreglo.map(
  (item, index) => console.log("el valor en " + index + " es " + item + " y sumado " + valor + " es " + (valor + item))
);
arregloSumado(6)
```

Comment: La ventaja de map es que crea un arreglo nuevo.

Comment: El ejemplo del map es incorrecto. Por cada elemento del array original se crea un elemento Console.log, el cual al no tener retorno es undefined. Es decir estas creando un array que dentro tiene `undefined`

Comment: @Yussef es verdad. El ejemplo está usando el map como si fuera un foreach. Está mal.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Viene perfecto para esto caso, pero debería ser algo así `miArreglo.map(a=>a+=5)`

Comment: lo que quiere es imprimir el mensaje solo abre tu consola y ejecuta. Y si map devuelve un array pero para que realizar la operación 2 veces es decir sumar en un map y despues iterar el nuevo array para imprimir los datos procesados???